# const char * to char * in my case

Tags: c++, string, strdup

Although I know that converting `const char *` to `char *` is almost banned in C/C++ because of many problems, I am caught up in a situation where I think I have to convert `const char *` to `char *`.

I get a string from a text file as string by using `c_str` and I want to modify this string. However the problem is that `c_str` converts string into `const char *`. So is it a good choice to use `strdup` in this case or is there any better idea in doing this?

Comment: Don't use `c_str`. Use `&s[0]`.

Comment: The best way is to copy, modify copy and then create a new string. Of course this guarantees correctness at a performance cost. You may also do the previous comment if you keep the same length. Shortening is implementation defined, lengthening is undefined.

Comment: Thanks a lot! and yes, I will keep the same length. @KerrekSB Why is using &s[0] better than c_str?

Comment: That depends on how you are going to use the modified string. Do you need the modified string as std::string, or you need it as an old C string?

Comment: @user31264 I actually need std::string. My way of doing this was by extracting char* from the string, modifying it, and then declaring new string with the modified char*. I came up with this idea because I had to modify sparsely located characters which seems to be inefficient if I use replase function.

Comment: What is `replase function`?   Also, are you allowed to modify the existing string, and not need to create a new one?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I actuall meant replace. Sorry for causing confusion

Comment: @wannaqc - if you need std::string, don't mess with old C strings.  
Aconcagua's solution is good, I upvoted it.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can modify the std::string object directly, as illustrated in the little program below:

```
int main()
{
    std::string s("Hello World");
    for(char& c : s)
    {
        c = toupper(c);
    }
    s[0] = 'h';
    s[6] = 'w';
    s.resize(12);
    s[11] = '!';
    std::cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

I think, it is self-explaining. Although you mentioned that size does not change, I added an example for that case, too, see [resize](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/resize/). There are yet other ways to manipulate the string, such as [insert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/insert/). Have a look at the [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) documentation.

Comment: Thank you! I solved the problem using your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

> Why is using &s[0] better than c_str?

std::basic_string class has `data()` and `c_str()`. However, as you know, these function's result type is `const CharType*`(CharType: `char`, `wchar_t`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`).

There is two way to get `CharType*`.

1. use `const_cast`. However, this is very dirty and break type system.
2. use `&s[0]`. `operator[]` **does not break type system.**

   ```
   #include <string>
   #include <type_traits>
   int main(){
       std::string s1 = "Hello world";
       static_assert(std::is_same<char&, decltype(s1[0])>::value, "err");
       static_assert(std::is_same<char*, decltype(&s1[0])>::value, "err");
       const std::string s2 = "Hello world";
       static_assert(std::is_same<const char&, decltype(s2[0])>::value, "err");
       static_assert(std::is_same<const char*, decltype(&s2[0])>::value, "err");
   }
   ```